# How to get facebook data of user with their permission

Tags: java

I want the facebook public data of my friends list using  " graph API ". For that I need to take friends permission according to my knowledge and research so far. Or Is there any other option to get friends data ? If so how to get their permission to get the public data ?

Comment: Show us what you've done so far.

Comment: I have posted the images of what I am getting in answer @Akshay Arora

Answer (score 0):

[This is how I am getting the data in image1 & image2. This is my data[![]
][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkxu7.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkxu7.png)

[Continuation of image1 [![]
][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNOxN.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNOxN.png)
But when I am trying to get my friends data I am getting it only by giving me i.e., as shown in image3.
My question is without me can't I get friends data by giving only their id or username ? @Akshay Arora

[image: I have shown the error in image4] ]